# Watch a specific filepattern to start a specific task in Laravel Elxir?

Tags: php, laravel, gulp, gulp-watch, laravel-elixir

I have setup a 2 custom tasks in my `gulpfile.js` :

```
var gulp        = require('gulp'),
    elixir      = require('laravel-elixir');

gulp.task('task1', function() {
  console.log('test1');
});

gulp.task('task2', function() {
  console.log('test2');
});

elixir(function(mix) {
  mix
     .task('task1', './resources/**/*.php')
     .task('task2', './resources/**/*.js')
     ;
});
```

When I run `gulp watch` I want only to see 'test1' when a `*.php` file is changed, and 'test2' when a `*.js` file is changed. But somehow ***both*** tasks are triggered when only 1 file changes.
Why is this happening ?

Is there a way to only trigger the right task ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this using Custom Watchers? See https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir under "Custom Watchers".

```
new Task('task1', function() {
    console.log('test1');
    // gulp.src here ect.
})
.watch('./resources/**/*.php');

new Task('task2', function() {
    console.log('test2');
    // gulp.src here ect.
})
.watch('./resources/**/*.js');
```

This could fix your issue.